# Join Multiple Tabls in SQL and Perform Arithmetic

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I need help with a SQL Query.

Database Table Samples:
Disease: http://i57.tinypic.com/qn1fg6.png
Interview: http://i60.tinypic.com/4smrk9.png

I have a query that is below:

```
SELECT interview.locationOfInterview as City, count(diseases.diseaseName) as diseaseTotal 
from diseases 
INNER JOIN interview on diseases.pID=interview.personInterviewed 
where interview.dateOfInterview = 2012 and diseases.diseaseName='asthma' 
group by interview.locationOfInterview
```

It gives the following results:

```
City  | diseaseTotal
Littleplace | 2
Smallville | 3
```

This query goes through and counts the amount of times the disease Asthma appears in a diseases table and links it with another table called interview which has the cities. It counts how many times asthma occurs in each city.

Next, i have another query that goes through a table and counts the population and gives the following results.

Query:

```
SELECT locationOfInterview, count(*)*200 Total from interview group by locationOfInterview
```

Results:

```
City | Population
Farmland | 1800
Littleplace | 3000
Smallville | 2400
```

For this specific problem, I need to keep the disease count and see how many times asthma occurs in 2012 in each city, but the population should be for all year, 2012-2014.

Both of these queries perform the correct actions and give the correct results, but I need to find a way to put them together so I can divide the City Disease Total by the City Population to give me a prevalence.

I came up with the following query, but its applieing the where clause to the population and only giving me the population for all people in 2012 instead of all the years (2012-2014)

Query:

```
SELECT interview.locationOfInterview as City, count(interview.locationOfInterview)*200 as Population, diseases.diseaseName as DiseaseName, count(diseases.diseaseName) as Disease Occurance
from diseases 
INNER JOIN interview on diseases.pID=interview.personInterviewed 
where interview.dateOfInterview = 2012 and diseases.diseaseName='asthma' 
group by interview.locationOfInterview
```

Result:

```
City | Population | Disease Name | Disease Occurance
Littleplace | 400 | Asthma | 2
Smallville | 600 | Asthma | 3
```

What I need the result to look like is:

```
City | Population | Disease Name | Disease Occurance
Littleplace | 3000 | Asthma | 2
Smallville | 2400 | Asthma | 3
```

I can figure out how to do the division after that. I am just having an issue because the where = 2012 is limiting the population.

Thanks for all help!

Comment: It isn't clear from your question why you are specifying `interview.dateOfInterview = 2012` but don't want only `2012` results. Why can't you just leave it out? (also, the column names in the results don't match the queries, which is confusing).

Comment: @turophile sorry, this problem is for a question where i need to show results of disease asmtha for only 2012. I changed up the names when making the post but I will edit it to clear it up.

Comment: In query 1 you are counting diseases, then in query 2 you are counting interviews (and multiplying by 200 to give population) BUT when you combine the two tables, the `count(*)` will be of the combined result, and is no longer the number in either table.

Comment: @turophile in the end I want a result so i can divide Disease Occurance / Little Place, such as 2/400 and then multiply by 100 to give me the percentage of prevalence

Comment: @turophile 
Database Table Samples:
Disease: http://i57.tinypic.com/qn1fg6.png
Interview: http://i60.tinypic.com/4smrk9.png

i have created some screenshots of my tables

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do what you want using conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT i.locationOfInterview as City,
       sum(case when i.DateOfInterview = 2012 and d.diseaseName is not null then 1 else 0 end) as diseaseTotal,
       count(*) * 200,
       (sum(case when i.DateOfInterview = 2012 and d.diseaseName is not null then 1 else 0 end) /
        count(*) * 200
       )
from interview i left join
     diseases d 
     on d.pID = i.personInterviewed and d.diseaseName = 'asthma'
where i.dateOfInterview = 2012 and 
group by i.locationOfInterview;
```

Comment: I tried this query and it returns the following:
http://i57.tinypic.com/2a9ochw.png

Comment: Database Table Samples:
Disease: http://i57.tinypic.com/qn1fg6.png
Interview: http://i60.tinypic.com/4smrk9.png

i have created some screenshots of my tables